# Почему возникает ошибка python(TabError)?

Tags: python

```
list0 = []
average, math_score, phys_score, rus_score = 0, 0, 0, 0
with open('text.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.strip().split(';')
        for i in range(4):
            if i > 0:
                average = average + int(line[i])
            if i == 1:
                math_score = math_score + int(line[i])
            if i == 2:
                phys_score = phys_score + int(line[i])
            if i == 3:
                rus_score = rus_score + int(line[i])
        average = average / 3
        list0.append(average)
        average = 0
inf = open('output.txt', 'w')
n = len(list0)
for i in range(n):
    inf.write(str(list0[i]))
    inf.write('\n')
math_score = math_score/(n+1)
phys_score = phys_score/(n+1)
rus_score = rus_score/(n+1)
inf.write(str(math_score))
inf.write(' ')
inf.write(str(phys_score))
inf.write(' ')
inf.write(str(rus_score))
inf.close()
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Python очень важны отступы. Также, для него отступы пробелами и табами - это разные вещи.
В данном случае, у тебя в месте, где ошибка - использовались другие символы для пробелов, нежели до этого момента.

Чтобы это исправить, проверь, используя свой IDE, что у тебя везде стоят одинаковы символы отступа, а именно, 4 пробела.